# Why are multiple debugging threads being started in integrated Python-debugging of VS Code?

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

### ** UPDATE **

From [a related discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/349#issuecomment-665123591) I got the following answer:

> Also, something to double check in your code is if the main entry point is protected by the `__name__=='__main__'` check:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> ```
>
> and depending on the structure, you could also need the `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` if you need to have multiprocessing support:
>
> i.e.:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     multiprocessing.freeze_support()
>     main()
> ```
>
> (if you don't have that structure, it may explain why multiprocessing is executing your main entry point code multiple times).

Yet, I have neither the first nor the second aforementioned option implemented and moreover, this sudden multi-threading behavior could happen with any script I execute.
It seems like old/previous debugging sessions are not really terminated behind the scenes, because in one session there is no multi-threading and then, later, a multi-session is launched when debugging.
This has also happened when executing the code normally and it exited with errors, and THEN I went (again) into a debugging session.

I'm not sure how to implement it, but should I put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

in the beginning of all my python-scripts which I execute as main-script, i.e. my entry-point or top-level script?

### ** ORIGINAL QUESTION **

As it can be seen in the **attached screenshot**, while carrying out the *standard debugging process* via pressing `F5` in `VS Code` (with some breakpoints defined previously), occasionally the following happens:

[image: Python debugging in VS Code]

This causes a lot of additional computing time, lagging and redundant console-output as the same code is executed several times in a row.

Oddly enough, this behavior seems to happen randomly. Only sometimes I could conclude that I attempted to launch a debugging session previously, which was interrupted at some point within the code by an `Uncaught Exception`, but still it doesn't seem logical to me why `VS Code` should relaunch all these previously failed debugging sessions along with a new one when pressing `F5`.

When interrupting the debugging procedure via `Shift+F5` or the red square button `Stop`, sometimes the message `timeout after 1000 ms` appears on the bottom right of the `VS Code` - window; especially when the issue occurred showing multiple undesired subprocesses and threads in the `call stack`.

The relevant part of my `launch.json` - file defining the integrated terminal debugging is:

```
{
    // !!THIS CONFIG-FILE IS USED FOR DEBUGGING!!
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            // VS Code Integrated Terminal. If redirectOutput is set to True, output is also displayed in the debug console.
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            // Make sure that code output is also being displayed in the debug console.
            "redirectOutput": true,
            // When omitted or set to true (the default), restricts debugging to user-written code only. Set to false to also enable debugging of standard library functions.
            "justMyCode": false
        },
...
```

As for the `settings.json` - file, I haven't implemented any options concerning *python debugging* whatsoever, apart from the generic option `"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true`.

I'd like to *understand why this undesired debugging behavior crops up* in the first place and finally to be able to prevent it from occurring.

---

**PS on trying to get an answer on the [official GitHub of VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode):**

I'd filed an [issue on the VS Code GitHub-page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103408#issuecomment-664398249), but was adviced to ask on StackOverflow since

> "VS Code only shows what is being requested by the Python debugger."

Comment: Kudos for this thoroughly researched issue across SO and GH!  I think I have a similar issue, with the debugger reentering my code with old arguments.  Guard code didn't help, but  just knowing about the problems that can arise from the multiprocessed debugger helps me troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [in this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/349).

To sum it up,

it is recommended to implement in the end of the *main script* (i.e. the starting entry-script from where the execution begins) the following:

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     multiprocessing.freeze_support()
>     main()
> ```

The line `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` won't do harm/nothing on UNIX-systems and works on Windows.
If the reader likes to learn more in-depth knowledge about this function,
see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) and [this part](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/349#issuecomment-671917933) of the GitHub-discussion mentioned above.

The essential part though (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/349#issuecomment-672107529))

> is calling `main()` from "under the guard"

where "guard" stands for `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Furthermore, as it had been explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/349#issuecomment-671536970),

> it should generally be at the end of your script, and all top-level
> code that's not already in a function should be inside `main()`. The
> reason is that your script is going to be imported as a module in
> every subprocess that multiprocessing spawns, so any top-level code
> will run many times without the guard. But only the instance that's
> directly started as a script will have `__name__ == "__main__"`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code multi-threaded or are these processes from you debugging in the past (but those processes not being killed off as intended)?

Personally I'm not observing this issue when going through Run -> Start Debugging- which I believe is the same as F5.

This is what my call stack section looks like as well my launch.json. Would make sure to hit stop or the disconnect button after you're done with a debugging session.

[image]

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My code is not multi-threaded. I always disconnect from the debugging process after I'm done (`Stop`-button, equivalent to `Shift+F5`). I assume that previous debugging processes aren't always killed/terminated as they should be after pressing the `Stop`-button (the red square in the debugging panel, which is equivalent to pressing `Shift+F5`). The question is why this happens and how one can resolve this issue. It happens only sometimes, but regularly in the recent month. Earlier this year I didn't have this issue.